# Content in floated divs causes div below to drop

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm displaying WordPress posts horizontally using floated divs. I've got it working fine, but when the divs move to a new row, if the paragraph text inside each floated div is too long, the div immediately below it drops. Furthermore, each floated div is affected by the length of the divs above it.

How do I make them flow naturally without being affected by the heights of those above them?

Here is my HTML for a single floated div:

```
  <div class="entry_column>
     <div class="entry">
       <h2>Entry title</h2>
       <p>Entry excerpt...if this text gets too long, the div immediately 
below it gets pushed WAY down</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br class="clearFloat" />
```

And here are the relevant CSS classes:

```
    .entry_column {
        float: left; width: 50%;
    }

        .entry_column .entry {
            margin-right: 25px;
    }

.clearFloat {
    clear: both;
    height:0;
    font-size: 1px;
    line-height: 0px;
}
```

I tried everything I could think of for the clearing, but if I try to add clearing directly on the floated divs, I still can't get it to stop dropping.

Hopefully the image explains this issue a bit better. The "More Music" box drops all the way down because of the length of the "Music Post Stand" div above it.

[image: Screenshot of problematic layout]

Comment: What styles do you have applied to the more music section? From the image it looks like it's set to clear the floats, which could be what's causing the issue. Do you have a link to a testing page that shows what's going on?

Comment: The more music uses the same style as the others. It's in the same floating box. Unfortunately I don't have a testing page online, as I'm developing it on my local computer using MAMP. I'll see if I can get it moved online tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

So the heart of your problem is that "This is Just Going To... Test Post" should be up against the far left, under "A music post stand"?

Try including the <br class="clearFloat" /> only at the end of a row of entry_columns, so in the screenshot you'd include it only in between "Another fun post" and "This is Just Going To... Test Post"

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.entry_column {
    float: left; width: 100px;
}

    .entry_column .entry {
        margin-right: 25px;
}

.clearFloat {
    clear: both;
    height:0;
    font-size: 1px;
    line-height: 0px;
}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="entry_column">
     <div class="entry">
       <h2>Entry title</h2>
       <p>
            Entry excerpt...if this text gets too long, the div immediately below it gets pushed WAY down.
            Repeated to make it long:
            Entry excerpt...if this text gets too long, the div immediately below it gets pushed WAY down
       </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  <div class="entry_column">
     <div class="entry">
       <h2>Entry title</h2>
       <p>Entry excerpt...</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br class="clearFloat" />
  <div class="entry_column">
     <div class="entry">
       <h2>Entry title</h2>
       <p>New row of Entries</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  <div class="entry_column">
     <div class="entry">
       <h2>Entry title</h2>
       <p>Entry excerpt...</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br class="clearFloat" />
</body>
</html>
```

(... at which point you should instead remove the <br /> and assign those entry_columns which are at the beginning of a row an additional class, and target that class with a CSS rule giving it the 'clear:both;' property.)

Comment: Yes, that is the heart of the problem, and your HTML example works well. The only issue is that I don't know how to achieve this with the WordPress loop...as in, how to add the <br class="clearFix"/> at the beginning of each row dynamically?

Comment: I'm not familiar with WordPress... could you include an example of the "WordPress loop"?

Comment: I got it working, spent a bit of time fiddling with the PHP. Thank you SO much for your help, Richard. The problem occurred because I was adding a float at the end of every element, when the float needed to be at the end of each row, like in your example. Thanks again and if you lived near me I'd buy you a drink! :-)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a syntax error. You forgot to close the class attribute:

> `<div class="entry_column>`

Answer (score -1):

If you can't add elements you could try using a CSS 3 nth-child selector to say 'clear every 5th entry_column. (for rows 5-entries wide)

```
.entry_column:nth-child(5n+0)
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/PR-css3-selectors-20091215/#nth-child-pseudo

It just may not be as cross-browser friendly as you need.